# Is Sun Java really necessary for using Android SDK on Ubuntu 10.10? I prefer OpenJDK

Tags: android, java

I would prefer to just use `openjdk-6-jdk` (version 6b20-1.9.1-1ubuntu3). But I'm just starting the Android SDK installation, so if Sun (Oracle) Java is really needed, I suppose now is the time to install it. Any advice?

Comment: You can always try it, but is it really worth getting a headache over?  If you are choosing that path on grounds of politics or principle, it might make more sense to avoid the java stage entirely and work on one of the alternative paths to generating the Dalvik bytecode that java byte code must be converted to before the device can execute it.

Comment: Rather than just blindly try it, I figured it would be smarter to ask here and take the advice of someone who has already done it! (FWIW, this isn't entirely political. It is simply easier to manage my machine if I only have one JDK installed. It helps that Ubuntu installed one that is free of political issues, but that's not my primary motivation.)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I'm using JDK for working on Android and it's fine :)

```
java -version
java version "1.6.0_20"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.9.1) (6b20-1.9.1-1ubuntu3)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0-b16, mixed mode)
```

And eclipse plugin too :)

Answer (score 4):

I tried it and it is working. I built and ran my project without any errors. (If I encounter errors in the future, I'll know to try the Sun JDK.)

Thanks for the feedback.

BTW, I'm running Ubuntu 10.10, and
Eclipse Helios Service Release 1 Build id: 20100917-0705
My project targets Android 2.2.
It works so far.

Answer (score 3):

> But I'm just starting the Android SDK installation, so if sun java is really needed, I suppose now is the time to install it. Any advice?

<strike>The Dalvik cross-compiler expects Sun bytecode and will fail with OpenJDK-generated class files, by all reports. Also, I'm not sure if there are any issues with other tools, such as the Eclipse ADT plug-in. You are welcome to try it, though.</strike>

OpenJDK and the official Oracle compilers work using modern versions of the Android developer tools. Other Java compilers (e.g., GNU Classpath for Java) may or may not work.

Comment: Has this changed? This seems to suggest that OpenJDK is preferred on Ubuntu: http://source.android.com/source/initializing.html#installing-the-jdk

Comment: @CJBS: OpenJDK is fine -- I use that myself. Google tends to prefer that you use Oracle's Java compiler, though I have not run into any problems with OpenJDK. I have updated the four-year-old answer to reflect modern reality.

Answer (score 1):

For an ["official" answer](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/discuss/2013-July/003090.html) (by Andrew Hughes, who is "Free Java Software Engineer" at Red Hat, Inc):

> We've never had any bug reports relating to this that I'm aware of.