# error installing java on ubuntu 10 64bit

Tags: java, android, ubuntu, installation

**EDIT**

I added this note to explain why I keep this question here. I added "Android" as keyword and I'd like to know whether someone else has tried to download the code and how it is possible to work around this problem. 
I fear that if I ask Ubuntu they would suggest me to use OpenJDK but the question is: did someone use that SDK to build Android code?

**ORIGINAL**

Sometime ago I downloaded the android source code on Ubuntu 10 64bit. 
I had problems but at the end I managed to get everything working.
Now I'm trying to do it again on a fresh install of the same Ubuntu version but I'm having a problem.

Although I followed the instruction [here](http://source.android.com/source/initializing.html) I keep having the error:

> Package sun-java6-jdk is not available, but is referred to by another package.
>   This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
>   is only available from another source
>   E: Package sun-java6-jdk has no installation candidate

Googling gives you a lot of results that all give you the same solution:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ lucid partner"   
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jdk
```

I did it but it didn't work.

I'm running Ubuntu on a VM under VMWare.

I have also tried to add another source:

> sudo add-apt-repository "deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu lucid partner

but it didn't help

Maybe the answer is here:

[Answer in SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/394770/installing-sun-java6-jdk-with-apt-get-on-ubuntu-10-04)

but it is weird that on the Android portal there isn't any mention of it

Comment: Shouldn't this be moved to Superuser?

Comment: I saw questions like this on stackoverflow

Comment: @herschel It's actually wrong place to be.  The best place for this question is on http://www.askubuntu.com, which has plenty of answers on the same thing: http://askubuntu.com/search?q=installing+sun+JDK

Comment: I have OpenJDK + Ubuntu 11.10 + Andoid SDK. I even managed to install USB drivers for the device and was able to debug my code, so all is possible :) I think I have installed OpenJDK from the official (default) source, and all installed smoothly. Only had problems with installing android extension on eclipse.

Comment: @Archeg it looks like your answer is what I was looking for. Maybe if you add an answer I can accept it if no other better answers come later

Comment: @Archeg Reading your answer again. You said you installed the Android SDK. What about the Android source code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you should now download JDK manually. Somewhere I found these steps and it worked fine in my case:

1. Download [Java SE 6 JDK for Linux x86](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk-6u31-download-1501634.html) self-extracting binary (if you work with 32bit platform)
2. From the download folder, make the file executable `chmod a+x jdk-6u<version>-linux-i586.bin`
3. Move the file to the jvm folder `sudo mv jdk-6u<version>-linux-i586.bin /usr/lib/jvm/`
4. Change to the jvm folder and run the self-extracting binary `cd /usr/lib/jvm`
5. `sudo ./jdk-6u<version>-linux-i586.bin`
6. Everything will be extracted to a new jdk1.6 folder and you
   can delete the .bin file now.
7. Make a symbolic link to the new java binary in the alternatives
   folder. `sudo ln -s -b /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6<version>/jre/bin/java
   /etc/alternatives/java`
8. Append in your ~/.bashrc

   > ```
   > JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.<version>/
   > ```
   >
   > PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
9. Double-check the version `java -version`

Remember that you can work only with JDK v6 version.

Comment: I guess in my case Path was installed because I have a previous version of java - that's why I did not need in this step.

Comment: check also this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3747789/how-to-install-the-sun-java-jdk-on-ubuntu-10-10-maverick-meerkat

Answer (score 3):

Ensure the following:

- make sure you have done `sudo apt-get update` to make sure you have the latest package information.
- since it says

> Package sun-java6-jdk is not available, but is referred to by another
>   package. This may mean that the package is missing, has been
>   obsoleted, or is only available from another source E: Package
>   sun-java6-jdk has no installation candidate

you can search `sudo apt-cache search sun-java6-jdk` or simply `apt-cache search java6` to see what it is referred from and then install that package if it has a different name.

- Maybe try removing any and all PPAs you've added (I think you may have more than one with some typos etc.) and then add it again [but using the GUI](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu)

Also, you could always use [OpenJDK instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4074711/is-sun-java-really-necessary-for-using-android-sdk-on-ubuntu-10-10-i-prefer-ope) or add a [3rd party PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ferramroberto/+archive/java)

Comment: HI. I'm sure a did "sudo apt-get update". The problem is known the question is whether there is a way (not the usual one) to install the sun sdk and/or whether OpenSDK has been successfully used instead

Comment: @herschel: The answer already says how to install the Oracle JDK: use a third party PPA, like the one linked. What's the problem? Oracle recently changed the licensing of their binaries, so Canonical (company behind Ubuntu) kicked them out of the repositories.

Comment: @herschel yes, the easiest way would be to use the 3rd party ppa. Also, I will say, I have successfully used OpenJDK, Eclipse, and the Android SDK to build Android apps.

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu 10.04 Lucid Lynx has Java 6 packages available, but you should activate partner packages first of all to download it from repositories. To do it, edit file `/etc/apt/sources.list` with command:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

and uncomment these lines:

```
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu lucid partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu lucid partner
```

then you can update repositories and install Java 6 packages with:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jdk
```

You don't need to add third-party repositories.

Comment: Have you tried running this in recent days? `sun-java6-jdk` isn't a package even after enabling that.

Comment: @Shurane I have not tried, because I used Ubuntu recent versions, but I think it has not changed in Ubuntu 10.04 Lucid Lynx. That is the question, an older Ubuntu version.