# How does the rendering iteration work in Android Native App using NDK, JNI in OpenGL ES?

Tags: opengl-es, android-ndk, java-native-interface

In OpenGL, to keep program rendering frames I need a `while` loop, all the code that put inside the loop is executed every loop. The loop looks like this:

```
while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
{
    // Check and call events
    glfwPollEvents();

    // Rendering commands here
    ...

    // Swap the buffers
    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
}
```

Now I'm jumping into OpenGL ES and trying to learn from this example:

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/master/gles3jni

However, I couldn't find any `while` or `for` loop in the code. Instead, There're something else likes extending the `GLSurfaceView` and implementing the `GLSurfaceView.Renderer`. I don't really get how it works.

Therefore, I wonder how the iteration goes every time it render a frame? Is every thing written in the .cpp file executed every loop or just functions that being called by the JNI? And once It finish rendering the very first frame, where does it start at the beginning of the 2nd loop? Your attention and help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Android, you do not need to do the looping yourself - the rendering loop is managed for you by the OS. It is implemented in `GLSurfaceView.Renderer`, which calls `onDrawFrame` which is called each frame, you just need to override this method in your renderer. It is all done in the Java code - if you wish to implement your OpenGL ES code in cpp, you create a rendering method in your JNI code and call it from your overridden `onDrawFrame`, like it is done in the project you are looking at.

Comment: So If I have a variable ``x`` that needed to be changed every frame, I could only put it in the method (``step()`` method in the above example), which is called through JNI from ``onDrawFrame``, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, you got it. If this variable is cpp, then you update it in 'step', if it is Java, you update it in 'onDrawFrame'

Comment: Glad to help. Good luck!

Comment: I have another question here :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42358194/how-to-debug-android-studio-project-using-ndk-and-jni-line-by-line-to-see-the. It would be great if you could take sometime to have a look at it. I would appreciate that.