# installing sun-java6-jdk on ubuntu 10.04 64 bit os

Tags: java, android

I am trying to setup build enviroment for android on my ubunt10.04 machine. For that i want to install sun-java6-jdk as mentioned in source.andoid.com .

> $ sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ lucid partner"
>
> $ sudo apt-get update
>
> $ sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jdk

But now I am getting the error as no package for sun-java6-jdk.

so I want to know how to install suitable jdk for android build set up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sun JDK was dropped from Ubuntu due to licensing nonsense: http://news.softpedia.com/news/Canonical-Will-Remove-Java-From-Ubuntu-241147.shtml . Use openjdk instead.

Although there is a ppa here https://launchpad.net/~sun-java-community-team/+archive/sun-java6  that lets you install the SunJDK, it's very out-of-date and looks abandoned.

Comment: But I have one doubt, on source.android.com they specify to download sun-java6-jdk, in this case will openjdk can be use for building android source code

Comment: See this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4074711/is-sun-java-really-necessary-for-using-android-sdk-on-ubuntu-10-10-i-prefer-ope

Answer (score 18):

you could install sun jdk for Ubuntu 10.04 in the same way as 10.10. The steps for installing java in 10.10 is described in http://java.dzone.com/articles/sun-java-6-ubuntu-1004-1010

here's the steps of installing sun jdk, taken from that article:

```
add-apt-repository ppa:sun-java-community-team/sun-java6
apt-get update
apt-get install sun-java6-jdk
update-java-alternatives -s java-6-sun
```

in case the repository mentioned above not available anymore, here is a manual-ish alternative in installing JDK: http://codingforme.wordpress.com/2012/05/14/installing-oracle-java-jdk-6-or-7-on-ubuntu-12-04/

Answer (score 0):

Download jdk-6u45-linux-x64.bin from Oracle repository and execute the below code

```
chmod u+x jdk-6u45-linux-x64.bin
./jdk-6u45-linux-x64.bin
sudo mv jdk1.6.0_45 /opt
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/opt/jdk1.6.0_45/bin/java" 1
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javac" "javac" "/opt/jdk1.6.0_45/bin/javac" 1
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/libjavaplugin.so" "mozilla-javaplugin.so" "/opt/jdk1.6.0_45/jre/lib/amd64/libnpjp2.so" 1
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javaws" "javaws" "/opt/jdk1.6.0_45/bin/javaws" 1
```

MORE ON : http://peesquare.com/blogs/install-sun-java-6-on-ubuntu-10-04-12-04-12-10-13-04-13-10-both-32-bit-and-64-bit-system/

Answer (score -1):

In my case, I'd rather download the required JDK directly from Sun's homepage. Once you download and unzip it, then all you need to do is simply adding an environment variable, JAVA_HOME. That's it. It is very simple and works regardless of ubuntu version.