# How to build android project with openjdk on Ubuntu?

Tags: android, ubuntu, java

I found this [Is Sun Java really necessary for using Android SDK on Ubuntu 10.10? I prefer OpenJDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4074711/is-sun-java-really-necessary-for-using-android-sdk-on-ubuntu-10-10-i-prefer-ope) but I can't build android project on Ubuntu. When I try:

```
$ ant debug
```

I got:

```
Unable to locate tools.jar. Expected to find it in /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/lib/tools.jar

...

BUILD FAILED
/home/kuba/projects/Android/android-sdk-linux/tools/ant/build.xml:651: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/kuba/projects/Android/android-sdk-linux/tools/ant/build.xml:672: Unable to find a javac compiler;
com.sun.tools.javac.Main is not on the classpath.
Perhaps JAVA_HOME does not point to the JDK.
It is currently set to "/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre"
```

I have java version:

```
$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_20"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.9.13) (6b20-1.9.13-0ubuntu1~10.10.1)
OpenJDK Client VM (build 19.0-b09, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Comment: Can you ouput `whereis javac` here?

Comment: `javac: /usr/bin/javac` - its perl script that execute `gcj`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure you have the openjdk `JDK` installed.  By default you probably only have the `JRE` installed.  If you open `Synaptic`, search for `openjdk` and then you'll see both the `JDK` and the `JRE`.  Select the JDK package and install.  I think the actual packagename is `openjdk-6-jdk`.

or use the commandline

```
# sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jdk
```

Comment: Great, thanks, I thought that I have JDK since I was able to use compler.

Answer (score 3):

Android's official webpage reccomends the use of the official JDK from Sun/Oracle that you can download at http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html , the use of OpenJDK is unsupported and highly unrecommended.

You don't need to install the official JDK in your system, if this is what you are worring about, just download the *.bin version of the JDK of your choice ( i suggest the 1.6 version ), unpack everything by executing the *.bin in a terminal, and just modify 2 environment variable like this:

- `PATH` , add the path to the jdk executables `path_to_jdk/bin/` to your `PATH`
- `JAVA_HOME` , set `JAVA_HOME` to the generic path of your jdk, NOT the `bin` or `lib` path, just as before without bin, only path_to_jdk/

you can modify this variables by editing the `/etc/bash.bashrc` or your local `.bashrc`, I suggest to edit the one under `/etc`

you also want to remove your actual OpenJDK from your system.

Comment: There is a way to install sun jdk from ubuntu repository, but I want to use open-jdk, but thanks for you anwser anyway.

Comment: i read the fact that you want to do that, but you will experience problems and the technolgies are different, if the Android team is suggesting this tool there is a reason, a very good one.

Comment: I once buy laptop with Windows XP on it and they recommend to use Windows and I still remove it and install Ubuntu since I prefer GNU/Linux.

Comment: Yeah, but now there is a technical reason for using the official JDK and not OpenJDK, even Tizen does not use the OpenJDK, if you care about open source software, don't worry, the official JDk is a GPL project from the 2007, if you care about the reason why you should have to do that: Android uses Apache Harmony as its java implementation, OpenJDK uses OpenJDK java implementation, they are 2 different implementation of java. Using OpenJDK you are just generating bytecode that can only cause problems.

Comment: @user827992. Ubuntu and other distros don't distribute oracle JDK because it is not fully gpl. For example, on their own download page, they ask you to agree to a license which is not at all open source: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/terms/license/index.html

Answer (score -1):

I've fixed same error (in Debian/Ubuntu) by installing `gcj-jdk`.
Before installing this package i had `java-7-openjdk`, but no `tools.jar` inside its directory.
After installing `gcj-jdk` I've located `tools.jar` and made a symlink to it inside  directory where ant wants it to be.

Comment: Rather use openjdk-*-jdk